# remove lines that are a sequential numbers in a text file

Tags: python

I have a file that is like this

```
1
Hello world
2
This is a second 
set of text
3
The world is crazy
```

I need to remove the lines that have the sequential numbers using Python.

Not able to find a similar topic on here.

Comment: is your file imported as a string or list of lists etc?

Comment: There are several ways you could do it.  Are the numbers strictly ascending, sequential, and starting from 1?  What have you tried so far and how are you failing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sequential. For example, if `1, 2, 4, 3` are found should 4 and 3 be picked and 1 and 2 dropped?

Comment: Its not clear what the requirements are. Can you post the expected result from your example? All of these numbers are sequential, so I'd expect the output to be nothing.

Comment: If this file can have non-sequential numbers, include an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

Below code would help you.

```
file1 = open('readfilepath.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('writefilepath.txt', 'w')
Lines = file1.readlines() 
  
for line in Lines:
  if (s.isnumeric() == False):
     file2.writelines(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can read your file into a list of strings with python. I'm using the following test set:

```py
test = '''
1
Hello world
2
This is a second 
set of text
3
The world is crazy
'''.strip().split('\n')
```

With the below code:

```py
def omit_sequential_numbers(lines):
    last = None
    for line in lines:
        try:
            number = int(line)
        except ValueError:
            yield line
            continue

        if not last or number == last + 1:
            last = number
            continue
        
        yield line

list(omit_sequential_numbers(test))
```

```py
['Hello world', 'This is a second ', 'set of text', 'The world is crazy']
```

You didn't gave a failure case, but should still return numbers not following a initial sequence.